# Generate a pdf from a pdf "template" in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pdf, meteor, pdf-generation

I'm looking to generate a pdf from an existing pdf "template". For example, the pdf "template" would have the, text, fields, and layout -- all that would be left to do is fill in "fields" with data.

I would like to populate these fields with the appropriate data from a mongo collection, and generate a new pdf from it.

I am looking at the pascoual/meteor-pdfkit package, but I only read about how to generate a pdf from scratch.  Also, I reviewed http://pdfkit.org/ but found no examples of my approach.

Is the above possible with an existing meteor pdf package?  What's the best way to go about this?

For example, the following is part of a pdf document, the "fields" need to be populated with data I get from a collection:
[image]

UPDATE: I'm looking into using pdftk server: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/ (the command line) to do form fill pdf (fdf).  This seems to do what I want, and runs on all platforms.

Comment: To be able to use a raw PDF as template you need to find a lib that allows to update an existing PDF, to write over. A lib not offering that cannot be used for templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using FDFs (actually XFDFs) to do the PDF form fills.  PDFtk server was the tool I ended up using.